# Silverlight image bind with .png not work

Tags: image, binding, png, silverlight-5.0

I was careful to check this in the forums, but I did not find a solution.

This works perfect:

```
 <Image Margin="0,0,0,0" Stretch="UniformToFill" Source="http://localhost:5313/Images/1.png"    MaxHeight="140" MinHeight="155" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
```

Why does this not work:

```
<Image Margin="0,0,0,0" Stretch="UniformToFill" Source="{Binding ImagenSeleccionada}"    MaxHeight="140" MinHeight="155" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
```

### The code behind.

```
    private string _imagenSeleccionada;
    public string ImagenSeleccionada
    {
        get
        {
            return this._imagenSeleccionada;
        }
        set
        {
            if (this._imagenSeleccionada == value)
                return;

            this._imagenSeleccionada = value;
        }
    }
```

Main Page

The Control

ItemsSource="{Binding FilteredTemperatureReports}" UseLayoutRounding="False"
                         RowHeight="20" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" SelectionMode="Single"
                         HorizontalGridLinesBrush="Transparent" VerticalGridLinesBrush="Transparent"
                         Background="{x:Null}" BorderBrush="{x:Null}"
                         IsFilteringAllowed="False" RowIndicatorVisibility="Collapsed" 
                         CanUserFreezeColumns="False" ShowGroupPanel="False" 
                         HeaderRowStyle="{StaticResource GridViewHeaderRowStyle}" 
                         GroupRowStyle="{StaticResource GridViewGroupRowStyle}" 
                         RowStyle="{StaticResource GridViewRowStyle}">

```
    <telerik:GridViewDataColumn Width="150" DataMemberBinding="{Binding Medio}" IsReadOnly="True" Header="Medio" 
                                                HeaderCellStyle="{StaticResource GridViewHeaderCellStyleFirst}"
                                                CellStyle="{StaticResource GridViewCellStyle}" />
    <telerik:GridViewDataColumn Width="80" DataMemberBinding="{Binding TimeStamp}" IsReadOnly="True" Header="Fecha" DataFormatString="{} {0:dd/MM/yyyy}"  
                                                HeaderCellStyle="{StaticResource GridViewHeaderCellStyle}"
                                                CellStyle="{StaticResource GridViewCellStyle}"/>
    <telerik:GridViewDataColumn Width="200" DataMemberBinding="{Binding Producto}" IsReadOnly="True" Header="Producto" 
                                                HeaderCellStyle="{StaticResource GridViewHeaderCellStyle}"
                                                CellStyle="{StaticResource GridViewCellStyle}"/>
    <telerik:GridViewDataColumn Width="180" DataMemberBinding="{Binding Version}" IsReadOnly="True" Header="Version" 
                                                HeaderCellStyle="{StaticResource GridViewHeaderCellStyle}"
                                                CellStyle="{StaticResource GridViewCellStyle}"/>
    <telerik:GridViewDataColumn Width="80" DataMemberBinding="{Binding Inversion}" IsReadOnly="True" Header="Inversion" DataFormatString="{}{0:C}" 
                                                HeaderCellStyle="{StaticResource GridViewHeaderCellStyle}"
                                                CellStyle="{StaticResource GridViewCellStyle}"/>
    <telerik:GridViewDataColumn Width="80" DataMemberBinding="{Binding Ytd}" IsReadOnly="True" Header="YTD" DataFormatString="{}{0:C}" 
                                                HeaderCellStyle="{StaticResource GridViewHeaderCellStyle}"
                                                CellStyle="{StaticResource GridViewCellStyle}"/>
    <telerik:GridViewColumn Width="80" IsReadOnly="True" Header="Product" 
                                                HeaderCellStyle="{StaticResource GridViewHeaderCellStyle}" 
                                                CellStyle="{StaticResource GridViewCellStyle}" >
```

The Code Behin the Grid.

```
void OnGridViewSelectionChanged(object sender, Telerik.Windows.Controls.SelectionChangeEventArgs e)
{
    var grid = sender as RadGridView;
    if (grid.SelectedItem != null)
    {
        grid.ScrollIntoView(grid.SelectedItem);
            var _internetDataViewModel = this.DataContext as InternetDataViewModel;
            _internetDataViewModel.ImagenSeleccionada = ((ExecutiveDashboard.TemperatureData)(grid.SelectedItem)).Image;
    }
}
```

What is not ok?

Thnaks

Answer (score 0):

The `{Binding}` does not automatically know where to locate `ImagenSeleccionada`.

You need to either link it to a specific element, typically your *named* user control:

```
<UserControl x:Name="ThisCtrl" .... >
    <Image Source="{Binding ImagenSeleccionada, ElementName=ThisCtrl}" ... />
```

or explicitly set the `DataContext` of your user control to itself; the `DataContext` will then propagate down to the user control children:

```
<UserControl DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" ... >
    <Image Source="{Binding ImagenSeleccionada}" ... />
```

(alternatively you can set the `DataContext` to `this` in the code-behind constructor,)

or you can set the relative source of your image binding to the ancestor that is the user control, preferably via its type:

```
<UserControl ...>
    <Image Source="{Binding ImagenSeleccionada,
           RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=local:YourUserControlType}}" ... />
```

Comment: Hi. Still does not work, what can i show you, for can get aditional help. Thanks. Charles.

Comment: If you are assigning `ImagenSeleccionada` *after* you have component initialization in the constructor, I believe these changes will only be picked up by the UI if you are using [dependency properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752914.aspx). I recommend that you replace your regular property with the corresponding dependency property.

Comment: Mr. Gustafsson. Thanks, but for this case. What you would use? Im goint to edit for show additional code information.